# Bash Script to generate hash value using DIGEST command

Tags: bash, md5

Can any one tell me how to use bash script to execute the command `digest -a md5 -v /filename`, and store the generated hash value to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too familiar with `digest`, but this should work

```
digest -a md5 -v /filename > digest.log
```